# For every positive integers $a$ and $n$, is it true that: $a^{n−1} \equiv 1 \pmod n \iff \gcd(a,n) = 1$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Based on [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) or on [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), is the statement

$$a^{n−1} \equiv 1 \pmod n \iff \gcd(a,n) = 1$$

true for every positive integers $a$ and $n$?

Comment: Try a few non-primes $n$, such as $4$ and $6$.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Thanks. What about the values of $a$?

Comment: Try $n=4$, and $a=3$, Of course $\gcd(a,n)=1$ but $a^{n-1}=3^3\not\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. The same sort of thing will happen with $n=6$ and $a=5$. But in principle one example is enough to show that the assertion is sometimes not true.

Comment: The other direction is always true. If $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ then $\gcd(a,n)=1$. Proof is easy. For if $a$ and $n$ had a non-trivial common divisor, that would divide $a^{n-1}$ and $n$, and therefore would divide $1$.

Comment: ie moral of the story is phi(n) doesn't necessarily divide n-1

Comment: @Jack Not $\,\phi(n)\,$ but [Carmichael $\,\lambda(n),\,$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) i.e. the exponent of $\,\Bbb Z/n^*,\,$ i.e. the least $\,k\,$ such that $\,a^k\equiv 1\pmod n\,$ for all $\,a\,$ coprime to $\,n.\ \ $

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Jack $\ a^k\equiv 1\pmod n\,$ is true for all $\,a\,$ coprime to $\,n\iff \lambda(n)\mid k.\,$ That is not generally true if you replace $\,\lambda(n)\,$ by $\,\phi(n),\, $ as your comment seems to imply. Btw, you need to write at-username if you want them to be notified of your comments. I saw your prior comment only by  luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is prime, then this is clearly true: $\text{gcd} (a, p) = 1$ is true for all $a < p$ and Fermat's little theorem does the rest of the work.

However, it is not true for all integers $n$. Take $n = 6$. We have $5^5 \equiv (-1)^5 \equiv -1 \pmod 6$. Indeed, for all even $n>2$, we have $(n-1)^{n-1} \equiv (-1)^{n-1} \equiv -1 \not\equiv 1 \pmod n$

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you.